# How to get the Latest repository Build version in Nexus Rest Api?

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, nexus

I am using the Nexus Rest Api as per my need. i have uploaded the files to my repository. i want to get the repository's latest version like below, for 2 - 3 versions , i can save the details into the array and do my process. if it is going beyond the limitation. that time the save the process will be lengthy one. so please suggest me.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "repository": "string",
      "format": "string",
      "group": "string",
      "name": "1.0",
      "version": "1.0",
      "assets": [
        {
          "downloadUrl": "string",
          "path": "string",
          "id": "string",
          "repository": "string",
          "format": "string",
          "checksum": {
            "additionalProp1": {},
            "additionalProp2": {},
            "additionalProp3": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    },{
      "id": "string",
      "repository": "string",
      "format": "string",
      "group": "string",
      **"name": "2.0",
      "version": "2.0",**
      "assets": [
        {
          "downloadUrl": "string",
          "path": "string",
          "id": "string",
          "repository": "string",
          "format": "string",
          "checksum": {
            "additionalProp1": {},
            "additionalProp2": {},
            "additionalProp3": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": "string"
}
```

please help me to get the latest version **"name": "2.0",
      "version": "2.0",**.
from my repository.

Thanks.

Comment: The [search API allows you to download the latest version of an asset](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/search-api#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset)

Comment: is there any other way to get the latest build version directly from url?

Comment: without using the password and username is there any possibilities to access the repository directly?

Comment: If anonymous access is enabled yes. https : // your.server/repository/reponame/com/foobar/component-name/maven-metadata.xml. The latest version should be available in that file.

Comment: where i can get the metadata.xml file?

Comment: in https://<your.server>/repository/<reponame>/<path>/<to>/<foobar-component>/maven-metadata.xml. Simply browse your repo from the nexus GUI to understand its structure.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to work with json.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    struct Item: Codable {
        var id: String
        var name: String
        var version: String
    }
    var items: [Item]
}
```

Decode your json string.

```
var response: Response?
func decodeResponse() {
    guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8),
        let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData) else {
            print("Not Response")
      return
    }
    response = decoded
}
```

Get highest version

```
func getHighestVersion() -> String? {
    return response?.items.sorted(by: { $0.version > $1.version }).first?.version
}
```

Comment: no. it is not related the structures. but anyhow thanks for your reply.